# Implement react canvas component in Angular

Tags: reactjs, angular

I'm pretty new to both Angular and React, and I have a React file using the react-sketch-canvas component that I want to implement in an Angular project.

I have installed and imported in the ts file both the react and react-sketch-canvas libraries for the Angular project but when I tried displaying just the canvas, the angular html produces an error.

canvas.component.html

```
<div class="content-wrapper container-xxl p-0">
    <div class="content-body">
      <div class="col-4">
        <app-content-header [contentHeader]="contentHeader"></app-content-header>
      </div>
      <ReactSketchCanvas
            strokeWidth={5}
            width={400}
            height={400}
            strokeColor="red"
            canvasColor="white"
          />
    </div>
  </div>
```

error:

```
Error: src/app/main/apps/canvas/canvas.component.html:17:9 - error NG5002: Only void and foreign elements can be self closed "ReactSketchCanvas"
17         <ReactSketchCanvas
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/main/apps/canvas/canvas.component.ts:23:16
23   templateUrl: './canvas.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component CanvasComponent.
```

I would love to know if it's possible to do this (or if it's impossible to do), the correct way to be implementing a React component in Angular (especially for this canvas) or any other suggestions!

Thank you in advance, and sorry if this seems like an absurd request!

Comment: Please add error messages as text instead of a screenshot. [ask]

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll change it now!